# Extend the behavior of the finish method of the class WizardArchiveFileResourceExportPage1

Tags: java, rcp

I want to extend the behavior of the finish method of the class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.WizardArchiveFileResourceExportPage1'. The finish method basically gets the list of type IResources to export. 
`executeExportOperation(new ArchiveFileExportOperation(null,
                resourcesToExport, getDestinationValue()))`
 I want to modify this list of resources(projects to export) in such a way, that resourcesToExport are first added to one folder(folder1) and then sent to executeExportOperation method for exporting.However, resourcesToExport  are of type IResource only. So, how can make folder1 and all its contents(the projects) as IResource?

Comment: `IFolder` and `IProject` are already derived from `IResource`. However `WizardArchiveFileResourceExportPage1` is an **internal** class so you are violating the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by trying to use it.

Comment: Our requirement is to extend the existing behavior of eclipse export functionality. So, we have to either extend or override its behavior.